# How to create new variables and assign column names in an efficient way using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to calculate new columns based on data that look like this:

```
structure(list(english_score = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L
), math_score = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L), science_score = c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002478ee34d50>)
```

I want to produce something like this:

```
structure(list(english_score = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L
), math_score = c(4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L), science_score = c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), english_level = c("Level C", "Level D", 
"Level C", "Level C", "Level D", "Level C", "Level D", "Level B", 
"Level D", "Level B", "Level C", "Level C", "Level B", "Level B", 
"Level C", "Level D", "Level C", "Level C", "Level D", "Level C", 
"Level D", "Level C", "Level B"), math_level = c("Level D", "Level D", 
"Level C", "Level D", "Level D", "Level D", "Level C", "Level B", 
"Level C", "Level C", "Level D", "Level B", "Level D", "Level B", 
"Level D", "Level B", "Level C", "Level C", "Level B", "Level B", 
"Level B", "Level D", "Level B"), science_level = c("Level C", 
"Level D", "Level D", "Level D", "Level C", "Level D", "Level D", 
"Level C", "Level C", "Level B", "Level C", "Level D", "Level D", 
"Level D", "Level D", "Level D", "Level D", "Level B", "Level C", 
"Level B", "Level C", "Level C", "Level D")), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x000002478ee34d50>)
```

So far, my approach has been to use a function to calculate the levels of the new variables...

```
myfunction<-function(x){case_when(x<2~"Level A",
                              x>1 & x<3~"Level B",
                              x>2 & x<4~"Level C",
                              x>3~"Level D")}
```

....and then, create the new variables and assign their names one by one.

```
DT[, english_level:=lapply(.SD, myfunction), .SDcols='english_score']

DT[, math_level:=lapply(.SD, myfunction), .SDcols='math_score']

DT[, science_level:=lapply(.SD, myfunction), .SDcols='science_score']
```

How can I simplify this process, preferably using data.table?

Comment: might be missing something as myfunction might just be an example. isn't it just `c("A", "B", "C", "D")[score]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this (I've called your data `DT` as `utils::data()` is a base R function):

```r
score_cols  <- grep("_score$", names(DT), value = TRUE)
level_cols  <- sub("_score", "_level", score_cols)

DT[, 
    (level_cols) := lapply(.SD, myfunction),
    .SDcols = score_cols
]
```

Also, your `myfunction()` uses `dplyr::case_when()`. This will work but some `dplyr` functions clash with `data.table` (`between()`, `first()` and `last()` with the versions I currently have). You can replace this with `data.table::fcase()`.

```r
myfunction <- function(x) {
    fcase(
        x == 1, "Level A",
        x == 2, "Level B",
        x == 3, "Level C",
        x == 4, "Level D"
    )
}
```

This should be faster than the `dplyr` version as well.

Additionally, with this particular function, you could in fact replace the case when type logic with assigning the `n`th letter in the alphabet as a grade:

```r
assign_letter_grade  <- function(n) {
    paste("Level", LETTERS[n])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option where you avoid the need to create your own function. Instead you could create a mapping table and then map each score to the grade level.

```
grade_map = data.table(
  score = c(1:5),
  lvl = paste(rep("Level", 5), c("A","B","C","D","F"))
)

lvl_cols = gsub("score","level", names(orig))
score_cols = names(orig)

# Group by Row
orig[, 
  (lvl_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {grade_map[score %in% x]$lvl}), 
  by = 1:nrow(orig), 
  .SDcols = score_cols
]

# Using merge
orig[, 
  (lvl_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    merge(data.table(score = x), grade_map, by = "score", sort = F)$lvl
  }), 
  .SDcols = score_cols
]
```

```
    english_score math_score science_score english_level math_level science_level
 1:             3          4             3       Level C    Level D       Level C
 2:             4          4             4       Level D    Level D       Level D
 3:             3          3             4       Level C    Level C       Level D
 4:             3          4             4       Level C    Level D       Level D
 5:             4          4             3       Level D    Level D       Level C
 6:             3          4             4       Level C    Level D       Level D
 7:             4          3             4       Level D    Level C       Level D
 8:             2          2             3       Level B    Level B       Level C
 9:             4          3             3       Level D    Level C       Level C
10:             2          3             2       Level B    Level C       Level B
11:             3          4             3       Level C    Level D       Level C
12:             3          2             4       Level C    Level B       Level D
13:             2          4             4       Level B    Level D       Level D
14:             2          2             4       Level B    Level B       Level D
15:             3          4             4       Level C    Level D       Level D
16:             4          2             4       Level D    Level B       Level D
17:             3          3             4       Level C    Level C       Level D
18:             3          3             2       Level C    Level C       Level B
19:             4          2             3       Level D    Level B       Level C
20:             3          2             2       Level C    Level B       Level B
21:             4          2             3       Level D    Level B       Level C
22:             3          4             3       Level C    Level D       Level C
23:             2          2             4       Level B    Level B       Level D
```

Comment: Why `by = 1:nrow(orig)`?

Comment: Since 'x' represents a column. I need to group by row to pass in each individual x value and not the entire vector.

Comment: @SamR - added an option without the need to group by row. In any event your solution is cleaner. I just wanted to take a stab at it

Comment: I like the option without the grouping. There are a few things that `data.table` is surprisingly slow at and grouping by row is one of them.

Comment: @SamR That's neither surprising nor specific to data.table. Calls to R functions are expensive, so doing it for each row must be slow.

Comment: @Roland it's certainly not specific to data.table. The package is noticeably much faster than `dplyr` or base R, to the extent that many commands run more or less instantly on my machine. So when there are certain operations which take a while then I am always surprised.